# can't upgrade to 12.04

Tags: upgrade, 12.04, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“An upgrade from 'precise' to 'oneiric' is not unsupported with this tool” error while upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126718/an-upgrade-from-precise-to-oneiric-is-not-unsupported-with-this-tool-error)

I need help I upgrade from 11.10 .But i can't continue the upgrade it says

CAN NOT UPGRADE

> An upgrade from 'precise' to 'oneiric' is not supported with this tool