# "An upgrade from 'precise' to 'oneiric' is not unsupported with this tool" error while upgrading

Tags: upgrade, 12.04

A brief electrical outage interrupted my 12.04 upgrade.  After many tries, which included trying to upgrade from a command line, I was able to access Ubuntu screens again.

I find that the 12.04 upgrade was indeed not completed; I am still running 11.10.  However, Update Manager does not give me the option of installing 12.04 now.

And, when I run Update Manager, I am asked if I want to execute a "partial install."  When I answer "yes," I receive the message above.  Besides a clean install, any ideas about what can I do to upgrade to 12.04?

Comment: Can you please post output of gedit /etc/apt/sources.list?:)

Answer (score 2):

Try running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

It means your upgrade crashed during the failed system upgrade.

Try this:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a Terminal window.
2. Run these commands:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   That might be sufficient to fix the problem. If not, continue on...
3. Run the command

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/*release
   ```

   and change everything in the file gedit brings up to:

   ```
   DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
   DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10
   DISTRIB_CODENAME=Oneric
   DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.10"
   ```

   Save the file.
4. Then run this command.:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/*issue
   ```

   And change the file to to:

   ```
   Ubuntu 11.10 \n \l
   ```

Now open the Update Manager and upgrade the OS as usual.

Comment: yes when I was upgrading and it crashed.I tried in terminal  sudo rm -rf... and nothing, tried the next one lsb_ rel... and it said     release: 12.04   codename :precise  Thanks for your helps

Comment: Please post output of gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`?

You didn't say if you're running a 32-bit or 64-bit system, as there are known issues with either involving ia32-libs and multiarch in upgrading to 12.04 beta2. (I assume you're upgrading to beta2?)

Detailed information is at:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/TechnicalOverview/Beta2#Upgrades